# How to consolidate billing for IAM users separately?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can someone point a direction, how to separate billing information for various IAM users ? So that everyone can see only the part they have generated themselves

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe AWS supports such a feature, because infrastructure in your account is not permanently associated with a user.  A typical solution is to use [Cost Allocation Tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html) to break down your bill by various cost centers.  You might also consider maintaining separate child accounts and [Consolidated Billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidatedbilling-when.html).